# Be Scheduled From...Through

Tags: meaning

I have a question about the standardness of the pattern "*be scheduled from...through...*" [here](http://www.baltimoresun.com/news/maryland/freddie-gray/bs-md-ci-gray-hearings-scheduled-20151007-story.html):

> The five other officers' trials are ***scheduled from January through March***.

Is "*scheduled from January through March*" an incorrect version of "*scheduled* ***to run*** *from January through March*"?  Or is the sentence in the article correct as written?

Comment: It's used that way. *scheduled from [point 1] **through** end [point 2]*. *to* is also possible. Say - *scheduled from [point 1] **to** end [point 2]*

Comment: It's not an _incorrect_ version; it's an _elided_ version. I think it's fine.

Answer (score 1):

It is certainly correct. According to the definitions of "through" in the [Cambridge Dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/through), it can be used this way in the American English Standard.

PS: Please click on the link "Cambridge Dictionary". I've linked it to the page where such an example is used to define the meaning of "through".

Answer (score 1):

The sentence is correct grammatically.

The word "through" in the sentence is a preposition used to mean "up to/until," and "including."  You can replace it with "to."  Besides, it's correct if you don't use the first preposition "from."  Look at the following sentences that mean the same:

> The five other officers' trials are scheduled from January through/to March.
>
> ....................................................scheduled January through March.